# Renaming standard buttons in related list

Tags: callout

I have created a custom object called `Call__c`. In my related list, the button on the related list says `New Call`. Is it possible to rename this to `Link Call` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new List view button which will have same URL as of "New" button. In Page Layout, related list section you will have option to choose butons.

Steps:

1. Create Custom button of type "List Button"
2. Behavior : execute javascript
3. Content source : Onlick Javascript
4. Code :

   window.location= "/a4e/e"; //a4e needs to be replaced

Comment: How do I get the URL?

Comment: I have updated answer, let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Thanks - I have done that, and I have added the button to the "Contracts List View", but the button doesn't show up? Am I adding it to the wrong thing?

Comment: HI Lily, my bad, actually you need to create List Button, no need to override new button. Can you please try again, above steps should work. After creating List button, in related list you can choose which button to show.

Comment: Hello, I have followed the steps, and have added it to the page layout related list, but it does not appear. very strange!

Comment: that is maybe because you don't have create permission on call__c object?